# Horizontally scrolling a <pre> tag that is an auto flex-item (or in one)

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox, pre

I can't seem to figure this out. After looking at (least)

- [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-doesnt-flex-item-shrink-past-content-size)
- [Pre code blocks stretch the content beyond screen width in a centered flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210799/pre-code-blocks-stretch-the-content-beyond-screen-width-in-a-centered-flex-conta)
- etc...

... I still cannot get my `<pre>` tag content to scroll horizontally to the width of my available viewport space based on my flexbox layout.

Here is a CodePen with my current setup: https://codepen.io/neezer/pen/BJjzzM

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 auto;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.header h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.pre {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='nav'>
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='header'>
      <h1>Horizontal problems</h1>
    </div>
    <pre class='pre'>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @LGSon Sure, or I could just delete the question. Either way, I'm happy I have a solution.

Comment: Questions are great, so lets keep it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still suffer from the *minimum size* issue of flex items.

In a nested Flexbox structure, it can also affect flex item's being a flex container (or an *ancestor* being a flex item), and in this case your `content` is one, and also needs to have its `min-width` set to `0`.

*As a side note, in this case the `min-width: 0` set on `pre` is not generally necessary when using `overflow` with a value other than `visible`, and could be removed (which I did in the Codepen).*

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMGJGW)

Stack snippet

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;                       /*  added  */
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 auto;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.header h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.pre {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='nav'>
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='header'>
      <h1>Horizontal problems</h1>
    </div>
    <pre class='pre'>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 auto;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.header h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.pre {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='nav'>
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='header'>
      <h1>Horizontal problems</h1>
    </div>
    <pre class='pre'>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
      <span>this is a really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, really, long piece of text
      </span>
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```